# CALayer hierarchy, Best way to draw it to a context exactly as its shown on screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation, calayer, cgcontext

What is the best way to draw a whole **CALayer** hierarchy to a context (hence a UIImage, PDF)?

My hierarchy contains **CATransformLayer**, **CATextLayers**, **CAReplicatorLayers** and **CAShapeLayers**.

It looks fine on the screen but I never get it to look the same in the UIImage (and I don't want to use a screenshot-like rendering, since I want the **CAShapeLayers** and **CATextLayers** to be rendered as a vertex graphic to PDF)

These are some problems that I'm facing:

1. The rendering ignores the zPosition property and the translation.z in
   the transform, it renders strictly by the order in the sublayers
   array.
2. My layers have frames/position/transforms mixed and often
   layers get moved around (pseudo-randomly) when rendering.
3. Sometimes **CAReplicatorLayers** are simply ignored and only the first instance gets rendered to the CGContext
4. As soon as a translation.z value of the transform is set to a non-zero value, that layer completely ignores its transfrom and renders itself at (0, 0), I worked around that by manually ordering the layers and setting the zTranslation to 0 but it's not very comfortable.

I hope somebody of you knows an easy and safe way to render everything to a context exactly as it is shown on the screen!